# Form submission not saved when using a dynamic redirect

Tags: redirection

I have forms where I use a form alter to set various form fields on the fly.
One of which is the Thank You page field that a user should go to after submitting.
Example `$form['submitted']['thankyou_page']['#value'] = 'my_page';`
I use the same form for multiple reasons so setting the thank you page to suit.

After setting these (which work fine) I then enter a function to do some processing of the form fields to a CRM.

The final section of this function is like this

```
try {
    $result = $client->CreateContact($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result = $e;       
}
  my_submit_handler2($values['thankyou_page']); // redirect
}
}
```

The processing works fine to CRM but my problem is that the form submission (result) doesn't save in Drupal and the auto-emails after submit fail to send too.
The redirect is done like this

```
function my_submit_handler2($f) {
  drupal_goto($f);
}
```

So I guess the submission is being interrupted?

How can I do these redirects without affecting the flow of the form submission?

Answer (score 2):

A form submission handler, as well a form validation handler or a hook to alter a form, should never call [`drupal_goto()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x) since it outputs a HTTP header and interrupts what Drupal is doing.

The correct way to redirect a form from a form submission handler is setting `$form_state['redirect']` in Drupal 7, or calling [`$form_state->setRedirect()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.9.x) in Drupal 8. The alternative for Drupal 8 is calling [`$form_state->setRedirectUrl()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirectUrl/8.9.x).

For Drupal 7, the following code would redirect the users to node/123?foo=bar#baz.

```php
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  'node/123',
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'foo' => 'bar',
    ),
    'fragment' => 'baz',
  ),
);
```